# Xcode 8 - Firebase Error with Reference

Tags: xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, xcode8

I am very new to using Firebase and I have been trying to follow online tutorials. However, I keep getting an error with the line:

> var ref = DatabaseReference.database().reference()

The error reads: "Instance member database cannot be used on type 'DatabaseReference'."

What am I missing or doing wrong? Any help would be much appreciated!

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase     

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!

var ref: DatabaseReference?    
@IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {

    var ref = DatabaseReference.database().reference()


    if myTextField.text != ""
    {
        ref?.child("list").childByAutoId().setValue(myTextField.text)

        myTextField.text = ""
    }

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/start), it should be `Database.database().reference()`. 
 `DatabaseReferenece` has no memeber `database().reference()`.

Comment: You're welcome :) if my answer was helpful, please accept it. Thanks!